# How can I allow Git commit messages like “fixes #3” to update Trac tickets?

Tags: git, trac

I have just installed Trac 1.0.1 on a server that also holds a Git repository. I’d like to be able to close Trac tickets by including things like “fixes #3” in the Git commit messages. This should pretty easy—by including a [`post-receive` hook](http://git-scm.com/book/ch7-3.html) in my repository, I can execute some piece of code (e.g. a Python script) after each `git push` to the server. But what piece of code to use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After running around for a while and following a couple of dead ends (including [the Trac Git page](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracGit), which is vague on this topic, and the [Git plugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/GitPlugin), which won’t actually work (?!) until [bug #7301](http://trac-hacks.org/ticket/7301) is fixed), I found the solution.

1. Connect your Git repository to Trac through the steps at [“setting up a Trac environment”](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracGit).
2. Enable the [Commit Ticket Updater](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/CommitTicketUpdater) plugin, either through the “Admin” section of Trac or by editing `trac.ini`.
3. Create a file called `post-receive` in the `hooks` directory of your Git repository, with the following content:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/ruby

   ARGF.lines do |line|
     fields = line.split
     oldrev = fields[0]
     newrev = fields[1]
     refname = fields[2].chomp

     if oldrev =~ /^0+$/
       revspec = newrev
     else
       revspec = oldrev + '..' + newrev
     end

     other_branches = `git for-each-ref --format='%(refname)' refs/heads/ | grep -F -v "#{refname}"`
     other_branches = other_branches.chomp.gsub /[\r\n]+/, ' '

     commits = `git rev-parse --not #{other_branches} | git rev-list --stdin #{revspec}`

     commits.each_line do |commit|
       system "trac-admin .../trac changeset added '(default)' #{commit.chomp}"
     end
   end
   ```

   Of course, replace “.../trac” with the absolute path to your Trac installation.

   I’m actually using Trac through [Virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/). If you are too, add this to the top of the file:

   ```
   require 'tempfile'

   def virtualenv_system(cmd)
     script = Tempfile.new('post_receive')
     script.write 'source .../virtualenvs/trac/bin/activate'
     script.write "\n"
     script.write cmd
     script.close
     system "bash #{script.path}"
     script.unlink
   end
   ```

   and replace the `system` call with `virtualenv_system`.
4. Make this `post-receive` file executable.

This is inspired by the approach given on [the Repository Administration page](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracRepositoryAdmin#ExplicitSync), combined with [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10425622/371228) about getting all of the new commits in a post-receive script. I believe that this script, while long, behaves correctly when you are pushing multiple commits and/or pushing commits to branches other than the currently-checked-out one. (The script given on the Repository Administration page does *not* behave correctly in these situations—it only looks at the most recent commit message from HEAD.)

After this setup process, any Git commits that contain strings like “fixes #7” will close the corresponding tickets in Trac. You can configure this a little with the options listed on the [Commit Ticket Updater page](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/CommitTicketUpdater). Specifically, you might want to change the value of `commit_ticket_update_envelope`; it’s not completely clear, but I *think* the default is set so that you have to include your commands in square brackets, like “Refactored MyAwesomeClass [fixes #42]”.

Comment: This sounds like the sort of thing you might consider using `git notes` for. http://git-scm.com/2010/08/25/notes.html

Comment: @KlasMellbourn That looks promising, although it would require even deeper integration into Trac ;-)

Comment: The final assertion is wrong. Actually the default behavior is, that just 'fixes #42' triggers, but all other details seem good. Especially dealing with virtual environment is, what makes this answer valuable, very good.